# Error while loading data from JSON file in angular

Tags: angular

i am encountering the following error while trying to load data from Json File :

URL for StackBlitz :: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w5ynp7

> > ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse:
> >     {"headers":{"normalizedNames":[],"lazyUpdate":null},"status":200,"statusText":"OK","url":"https://angular-w5ynp7.stackblitz.io/app/T
>
> reeTable/data.json","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http
>   failure during parsing for
>   https://angular-w5ynp7.stackblitz.io/app/TreeTable/data.json","error":{"error":{},"text":"\n\n\n  https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro:400,700|Lato:400,700,900\"
>   rel=\"stylesheet\">\n  \n  \n  https://c.staticblitz.com/assets/preview-8222014a50f8588c56d057621cdaf871.css\"
>   />\n  https://c.staticblitz.com/assets/common-209bfed278c493d9677aa.js\"
>   crossorigin=\"anonymous\">\n  https://c.staticblitz.com/assets/ext-08c1b71abc0bf1dd4138a.js\"
>   crossorigin=\"anonymous\">\n  https://c.staticblitz.com/d/webcontainer.242365d931bb8c63e4a.js\"
>   crossorigin=\"anonymous\">\n  https://c.staticblitz.com/assets/preview-c35b6c3f1aa2eeeddb9ba.js\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\">\n 
>   (function(){_preboot(\"https://l.staticblitz.com/b/v1/angular-w5ynp7/166a3be1edf\",{p:\"stackblitz\",a:\"AIzaSyBZSvuCzbUhuRrSps-HjM5bFClLPaFF9Vg\",o:true})})()\n\n\n\n"}}
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
>       at eval (zone.js:873)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.ts:262)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
>       at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
>       at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
>       at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)

Please let me know where i am going wrong.

Comment: Please share some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON files can't be served from the directory where you put them. They must be under `src/assets`, and their URL will be `assets/...`.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewkq1h?file=src%2Fapp%2FTreeTable%2Ffileservice.ts)